# Fail2Ban does not work with nginx HTTP Auth

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I'm trying to set up some jails related to Nginx. But I noticed that fail2ban bans the IP with IPTables, but I still can use the form to log in.

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
maxretry = 3
action = iptables[name=SSH, port=xxxxx, protocol=tcp]
         telegram
port    = 23561
bantime = -1
findtime  = 30m
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s


[nginx-auth]
enabled = true
filter = nginx-auth
action = iptables-multiport[name=NoAuthFailures, port="http,https"]
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*error*.log
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 6

[nginx-login]
enabled = true
filter = nginx-login
action = iptables-multiport[name=NoLoginFailures, port="http,https"]
         telegram
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 6
 
[nginx-badbots]
enabled  = true
filter = apache-badbots
action = iptables-multiport[name=BadBots, port="http,https"]
         telegram
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 1
 
[nginx-noscript]
enabled = true
action = iptables-multiport[name=NoScript, port="http,https"]
         telegram
filter = nginx-noscript
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
maxretry = 6
bantime  = -1
 
[nginx-proxy]
enabled = true
action = iptables-multiport[name=NoProxy, port="http,https"]
         telegram
filter = nginx-proxy
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
maxretry = 0
bantime  = -1
```

My filters are taken from: https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/554-how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban

Comment: Show the complete `iptables` chains.  Is nginx running inside a container?  If so, the regular `INPUT` chain will not affect it.

Comment: My iptables chain: https://pastebin.com/6tL6idwr
I'm running Fail2Ban on a Debian VPS